Is a transgender woman allowed to be friends with women?
I am aware that transgender identity is considered haram in Islam. However, some people choose to worship Allah but may struggle to fully submit to His wishes, resulting in compromises.
In Islam, mixing genders is haram, and one shouldn't have friends of the opposite gender. So, should a transgender woman have female friends or male friends?
I’m curious because of a story I heard in which Muhammad ﷺ forbade his wives from having contact with a feminine man because he sensed lust in his behavior and words. This implies that the rules about who can befriend whom are tied to sexual preferences rather than biological sex.

As men are not allowed to wear women clothes an vice versa, so if this haram for clothes, it is obviously even more haram to wear the body of the opposite sex.

I certainly agree, but someone commiting a sin, doesnt make them less muslim, and my question did adress something else.

How do you define "be friends with"? Meeting in the bedchamber? Or having a meal together? Or feeding a hungry neighbor? Or defending someone against wild animals?

frequently talking, and potencially eating (as part of a group) togehter.

In this sense of the word, I my self do not see any obstacles. But @UmH always is rich in knowledge of references, pro or cons.

I feel I misscomunicated my question. I am of the belife what mixing is haram, and you souldnt have friends of the opposed sex, or gender. Sould a transwoman have therefore female friends, or male friends?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Under Islamic law a transgender person (مخنث) is considered to be male or female depending on their physical anatomy at birth and not depending on their preference. The rules that apply to them are based on this identity. So if one is a male according to Islam then the rules that apply to males will apply to him,
such as inheritance, testimony, marriage etc.
As for entering upon women, then note that the rules of hijab are relaxed for some men, among which are:

أو التابعين غير أولي الإربة من الرجال
or those male attendants having no physical desire
— Quran 24:31

There is disagreement on who is included in this relaxation, such as an a castrated person, a very old man, one with intellectual disability, a eunuch etc.
The wives of the Prophet ﷺ thought that an effeminate person was included in this, as stated in the hadith:

كان يدخل على أزواج النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم مخنث فكانوا يعدونه من غير أولي الإربة
A mukhannath used to enter upon the wives of Prophet (ﷺ). They (the people) counted him among those who were free of physical needs.
— Abu Dawud and  Muslim

But this person's recommendation of a woman and describing her appearance proved otherwise and he was removed by the Prophet ﷺ. The Prophet ﷺ gave a general prohibition regarding such people:

‏ لا يدخلن هؤلاء عليكن
These effeminate (men) should not enter upon you
— Bukhari

The scholars differ on whether an effeminate man is included in the meaning of غير أولي الإربة in the Quranic verse. If he has sexual desire then he is not included by consensus. Otherwise if he is like that from birth (rather than one who changed his behavior with time) then some have included him in the relaxation and others have excluded him because of the general meaning of the hadith above.
